# How to implement an editable wxListCtrl (for all columns)?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

When I am creating wxListCtrl in report view with wxLC_EDIT_LABELS flag, only the first column of the control is editable. Is there a way to make all columns editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because the native Windows control doesn't support this. To have this feature you will have to use [wxGrid](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html) or [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) instead. The latter is much more wxListCtrl-like but you should probably upgrade to 2.9.0 before starting to use it as it has many improvements there compared to 2.8.